# How do you get Netflix-Desktop to run for multiple users?

Tags: filesystem, guest-session, netflix

Netflix-Desktop keeps telling me I do not have extended filesystem enabled on the guest account. I would like to allow my sister to watch Netflix on my laptop without giving her my password.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to download the application, but, when I play a movie the screen remains black... Here is how to download the application but the screen stays blank when launching the application. If you can figure out how to get past the black screen please share.

Open terminal enter the following

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
```

Enter your password when prompted and then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

Open dash and click on Netflix.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a complete answer to this, but I'm having the same issue and am working on it as best I can.  I'm a humanities guy who is only a week or so into Linux and almost no experience writing commands.

I played with this command as a sort of schematic of what "extending user attributes" looks like:

```
setfattr -n user.foo -v bar test-file
```

I don't remember what exactly I ended up with, but I did something correctly and was told by the Terminal to first create a user attributes platform, so to speak.  The Terminal gave me the exact command to enter, which I did, and it worked.  But after that, in reference to the above `setfattr` command, I was told that "netflix-desktop" was not a file.  My next guess would be to try the same command with pipelight rather than netflix, but I haven't had the chance to try it.  I hope this helps, and maybe somebody else can take it from here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please review the information in [this page](http://askubuntu.com/tour) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/help) to get a general idea of how to best use this site. In summary, we strive for complete answers in the answer section. Partial answers and suggestions are preferably posted as comments. You'll need to put in some effort to gain some reputation and the privilege of posting comments that comes with it.